# Google login 2 factor authentication sms -fake or real?

Tags: authentication, password-management, google, multi-factor, sms

All my 2 factor authentication used to come from Google sms, but recently I've had the following numbers come up on my phone. I realise that to do this the person would need to have my phone number. I checked and this seems to be a number in canada. I did have a strange phone call from canada about a week ago but not sure if this is connected. Does anyone know if this is just my jumpiness or if this a legit attack. If it is, how can I prevent?

[image]

Comment: Are they valid 2fa codes?

Comment: This doesn't look legit to me. The CO on each number is different, which doesn't make a lot of sense for the official number—they would use a shortcode or numbers within the same CO as their official number. The way the text message is phrased is also pretty suspicious: why would they send you such a cryptically worded message?

Comment: Another point: they do have a Toronto office, but it appears to have a number in the 416 area code rather than in 647.

Comment: it timed out in the tor session so not sure if this is just because it couldnt load for some reason or because this is not legit. When I tried again, the sms returned to the normal google sms origin

Comment: Thanks @demize- it is weird, but who knows. I'm hoping they have some secret servers somewhere close to toronto which are firing these sms.

Comment: More worrisome, I think, is that two different numbers sent you the same code, at different timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

These appear to be valid Canadian numbers but are not Google numbers so not legit. Also not likely to actually be from the numbers listed. Far too easy to spoof caller ID's I'm afraid.

Scammers don't need your number, most operators have a range and auto-dialers can call huge numbers of phones in a short space of time.

Unfortunately there is little you can do though it may be worth reporting to your carrier, your local telecoms regulator and your local law enforcement organisation specialising in cyber crime if you have one (Action Fraud in the UK for example). Although you won't normally get much response, occasionally, when a large number of reports are received, something may be done about it.

Comment: The odd thing is that they seem to be redirecting me to my legit gmail after login. So it might be they're just after collecting my username and password and perhaps spying on my session by getting my ip? Why else would someone do this?

Comment: Your response indicates that you followed some instructions (clicked on a link?) and logged in? If so, I strongly recommend you immediately reset the password and change it anywhere else you might have reused it.

Comment: Hi, I changed to another phone number but it reverted back to the first one. I did call google but got the wrong department. He tried to assure me all was ok. I told him I was sceptical. I'm being redirected to my email but how are they doing that then if it's a fake number?

Comment: Hi again, just an update. I've spoken with the isp and then to google support. They asked me to raise it in the their forum. i'll keep it open here too as I think it might help others. I'll see what response I get and will post here once I have an answer.

Comment: That shouldn't happen if you've removed the old number in your Google profile.

Comment: i get lots of timeouts so it's hard to say whether it actually was confirmed or not.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be getting sms from different numbers which is scary. In India my mobile no. Is registered to multiple email ID but everytime I recieve a sms it is from a constant number.
[image: Each Sms from google has arrived on same number]

Change your password soon & possibly use google authenticator application. You might not be in attack with Man In Middle because I have seen gmail throwing me an error of untrusted connection when i had tried to filter my web content using openDNS (google uses https). But it can be a attack of phishing which later on redirects you to your google account.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Surendra Patil . I'm looking at those options, definitely, but I really would like a definitive answer from google and see whether they can do something to prevent this. I've already changed my password once. Then tried to change phone numbers and got a timeout. Waited and tried again on tor and got to change numbers. On new number it is all ok and comes up as google each time. However, this is really scary stuff and I think google needs to know about it and maybe try to put in some remediation. Maybe you're right and the only option is an app service for now...

Comment: These def not legit numbers. I called one of the people and spoke to her briefly. I believe this is an iPhone security issue. This is not just a random SMS for phishing. They are correct codes and only happens on one phone so when I tested with another phone it was fine. It also happened with another app that uses 2 factor authentication. It has been escalated with apple and I'll let you know what happens. I suspect my SMS messages are being intercepted and copied somehow. Two ways this might be done a) fm or other uncontrolled radio signal with Siri or b) imei number being known to attacker.

Comment: Omg... Will wait for your answer... Thanks for coming back & informing us....

Comment: I was likely the victim of an ss7 attack. You can google it but it's a flaw in the telco infra that is known to hackers and means if you know someone's number you can track location, listen to calls, forward calls and SMS messages and spy on everything. There is no way to get rid of it. I think the person got my number when I turned on 2 factor authentication on that was already compromised and hacked. I also suspect there's another hack on my phone via Bluetooth but not as sure about that one, and that can control my web page access. Apple is confirm likely hack but don't know what.

Comment: I did read about it, watched few videos about SS7 attack. It seems that it is known vulnerability since a decade, previously people have faced this same issue & its strange to see that it does not have a fix yet. This is going to be a big problem if not fixed soon...  regarding other hacks happened to you... Did you ever jailbreak this iphone ?

Comment: Sure is a big problem! I've never jail breaked my

Comment: Phone but I suspect someone else did as I'm getting other issues like dos and hijacking of web sessions. Too weird! Apple is still working with me and are

Comment: Escalating to the next level of product engineers for review. They're pretty responsive and have been good so far. Let's see what happens. I factory reset and still have dos and strange pop ups. I told apple the problem might have started with Bluetooth or similar near field radio device - fm? I rarely use Bluetooth but I turned Bluetooth earphones on at the building communal gym and my screen went dead after about 10 minutes and then strange numbers started appearing on my screen. telco will confirm it's ss7 and I'll close this question.

Comment: Thank you... Please update us with futher details before closing the question. If it would have been an android i would have asked you to Erase cache, dalvik cache and wipe data followed by factory reset from recovery... I have no idea how its done on iphone... Thanks for updating us so far...